# Can I prevent a field from being disabled on the Manage form display page?

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom content entity field that is required. I allow the form display to be configurable:

```
->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

That lets a user configure the Textfield widget for the field; however, it also lets a user make the field hidden/disabled. Since this field is required, that breaks the form.

When I looked through Core to figure out how other modules might handle this, I found that the same problem exists for Taxonomy. The "Name" field can be disabled, but it's required, so disabling it causes errors.

Is there any way to fix this issue or do I just need to rely on Site Builders to not remove a required field from the data entry form?

Comment: Probably this is a core bug. If using the GUI you can hide a field that is required and then that entity form trhow errors because that field is not populated (and it can't, because it's not int he form) then I see a bug.

Comment: I think there are valid use cases for entity form modes where a required field is hidden, so this is not a bug. But a warning message would be nice.

Comment: We have many required fields that are not displayed (it's up to us to populate the fields value)